# Angular performance around one shot observables

Tags: angular, performance, observable, ngrx

In my angular app, since I implmented the ngrx store, I have a lot of use case where I use observables for one shot query only. For example, when I get the items of my menu in header I know once they are loaded that they won't change. I wonder if this is usefull to implement the one time reading instead of keeping the observable "opened" with the pipe async, or does observables don't consume a lot of performance and it doesn't worth it?

Let's take the simple example below with the two different implementations. Firstly, I have the simple classic use of these observables queried through a facade (where menuItems are BehaviorSubject connected to the items in the store) and the async pipe in the template

my.compenent.ts

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  public menuItems$: Observable<item[]>

  constructor(private myFacade: MyFacade)

  ngOnInit(){
    this.menuItems$ = this.myFacade.menuItems$.asObservable()
  }
```

}

my.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of menuItems$ | async">{{ item.label }}</div>
```

But I can't keep thinking that from my template I am "observing" the menuItems$ from my component while I know they won't change! Should I change this and implement all the logic to observe the menu items only once, or is the performance gain for this doesn't woth it?

my.compenent.ts

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent {
  public menuItems: item[]

  constructor(private myFacade: MyFacade)

  ngOnInit(){
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.myFacade.menuItems$
          // with 'first' operator we take the first emited value 
          // that actually contains the menu items, avoids the null 
          // very first emited value at facade build and self unsubscribe
         .pipe(first(items => items.length > 0)
         .subscribe(items => this.menuItems = items)
    )
  }
}
```

my.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of menuItems">{{ item.label }}</div>
```

In this last version, there is more code, but "observation" is done only once then I don't listen anything any more (also in that case I don't handle unsubscribe because I know I will get my first not null values, but for some other entities I don't and so I have to handle unsubscriptiopn with more code). Does it worth it for performance? Or is it the same?

Answer (score 1):

`async` pipe will allow you to seamlessly use the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and will do the unsubcribe for you.

Just for that, I'd say I prefer the `async` over the latter.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't implement the OnDestroy and unsubscribe. That is not really my question. I ask if I should avoid to keep an observable "opened" (with aync pipe) if I know I'll use read only the first emited value and that there will be no more emited value after that.